# Angular: want to update dropdown list based on value chosen in another drop down

Tags: angular, typescript

I select daemon value (place, name or thing) and each of this daemon have dedicated productlist ( once again a drop down). I have replicated this in stackblitz here [stackblitz of code what I tried](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ccvn5).

What I am not able to do is update the second dropdown based on the value of daemon selected.

Comment: how does your `list` textbox works?

Comment: Ideally it must have shown 
 product list depending upon daemon chosen similar to angular auto complete https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples

Comment: Have you debugged `_filterGroup`? Your map is returning undefined. And you're calling `_filter()` which is not defined.

Comment: This is the original code from angular demo https://stackblitz.com/angular/aprpeybylrd?file=app%2Fautocomplete-optgroup-example.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your `selectDaemon` function as below

```
selectDaemon(value){
   console.log("daemon selected"+value);
   this.globalValueDaemon = value;
   let selectedProductList = this.stateGroups.find(item=>item.daemon==value).productlist;
   this.productGroupOptions=of(selectedProductList)
}
```

Add the import for the `of` operator as

```
import {Observable,of} from 'rxjs';
```

and remove the assignment to `this.productGroupOptions` from `ngOnInit()`

[**Updated Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dv1jgt)

Comment: Hey Aravind, thats awesome

Comment: I also want the data to be filtered as I type in value

Comment: @karansys I didn't understand your question

Comment: Now, based on daemon value data is populated but as one more step, as we type value in the input box values will be filtred. For ex: daemon = name as type 'b' it shows only names that start with 'b' .

Comment: to be be more clear , I want to implement Angular auto complete https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples